# Sorted Search, count numbers less than target value

Tags: java, algorithm

I am practicing a sorted search task, from [testdome.com](https://www.testdome.com/)

```
/**
 * Implement function countNumbers that accepts a sorted array of unique integers and,
 * efficiently with respect to time used, counts the number of array elements that are less than the parameter lessThan.
 * <p>
 * For example, SortedSearch.countNumbers(new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7 }, 4)
 * should return 2 because there are two array elements less than 4.
 */
```

Currently according to the site my answer has a score of 50 % due to edge cases and performance, im trying to get an opinion on what i might need to add or a different approach.
Here is my code

```
 public static int countNumbers(int[] sortedArray, int lessThan) {
        int count = 0;
        if(sortedArray == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        List<Integer> numbers  = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedArray.length; i++) {
            if (sortedArray[i] < lessThan) {
                count++;
            } else  {
                break;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

And the result i get when i test it on their environment is as follows

> Example case: Correct answer
>     Various small arrays: Correct answer
>     Performance test when sortedArray contains lessThan: Time limit exceeded
>     Performance test when sortedArray doesn't contain lessThan: Time limit exceeded

so two performance tests fail even though i cant see this tests may be i could get a suggestion here

Comment: Since the array is sorted, why not do a binary search for the target value?  The resulting index will tell you how many values are smaller.

Comment: could you show a little code on that, i didnt know how to divide the array, i mean we need to divide based on target value and not just in the middle

Comment: Don't have time to write the code, I have other commitments, but `Java.util.Arrays` has built-in binary search methods.

Comment: and how does that improve performance ? my code already loops only through the values that are less than target,

Comment: testdome @Abra you are right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `O(n)` is giving TLE. You need something faster than `O(n)`. Binary Search is `O(logN)`.

```
public static int countNumbers(int[] sortedArray, int lessThan) {
    int start = 0;
    int end = sortedArray.length - 1;
    int mid = 0;
    while (start <= end) {
        mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
        if (sortedArray[mid] < lessThan) {
            if (mid < sortedArray.length - 1 && sortedArray[mid + 1] < lessThan) {
                start = mid + 1;
                continue;
            } else {
                return mid + 1;
            }
        }

        if (sortedArray[mid] >= lessThan) {
            end = mid - 1;
        } else {
            start = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Or use built-in Binary Search:

```
Arrays.binarySearch(new int[]{1, 2, 4}, 3) + 1) * -1;
```

When the key is not found, it returns negative insertion position. To convert it to index, I did `+ 1` and multiplied by `- 1` to make it positive.

Comment: what is TLE ? @Harshal'

Comment: Time Limit Exceeded.

Comment: BTw we are returning mid + 1 because  our index counts from 0 right  @Harshal Perekh

Comment: Yes, because `start` is 0.

Comment: trying to understand why if  sortedArray[mid + 1] > lessThan then mid +1 is the answer